# Arabic digits added to routes using VpnService Builder addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0)

Tags: java, android, vpn, arabic

When device language is set to Arabic, the app won't connect to VPN. Here is what I found in log:

```
D/VpnJni: Address added on tun0: 26.26.26.1/24
E/VpnJni: Invalid route:  0.0.0.0/٠ 8.8.8.8/٣٢
```

Builder constructor has:

```
.addAddress(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, PRIVATE_VLAN, "1"), 24)
```

I have to lines with addRoute in my code:

```
builder.addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0);
builder.addRoute("8.8.8.8", 32);
```

So I tried to make localized string and convert it to integer:

```
builder.addRoute("8.8.8.8",  Integer.decode(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%s", "32")));
```

And tried to use NumberFormat and decode integer from it:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);    
builder.addRoute("8.8.8.8", Integer.decode(nf.format(32)));
```

But no success! It seems that Builder is ignoring any locale settings for addRoute but addAddress is ok with that. I haven't found any straightforward way to force the app to use exact locale.

Any thoughts? What am I missing here?

**EDITED:**
Based on @joop-eggen answer I thought I can somehow access and change set routes and replace incorrect chars. But there is no such method or whatever to change once it's set. Routes are indeed incorrect as I can see from the debugger:
[builder instance routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82gT2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you are passing a String for an InetAddress.

You can repair that string (assuming source UTF-8 or other appropriate encoding for .java) as:

```
a = a.replace('٠', '0')
     .replace('١', '1')
     .replace('٢', '2')
     .replace('٣', '3')
     .replace('٤', '4')
     .replace('٥', '5')
     .replace('٦', '6')
     .replace('٧', '7')
     .replace('٨', '8')
     .replace('٩', '9')
     .replace("\u200E", "") // LEFT-TO-RIGHT marker char
     .replace("\u200F", ""); // RIGHT-TO-LEFT marker char
```

The cause is probably some format (not String.format, but NumberFormat or such),
that converted a number to a String.

***I am not familiar with RTL numbers, and do not know whether 123 would become 321 with the above.***

Comment: But I'm simply setting it in here: `builder.addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0);
builder.addRoute("8.8.8.8", 32);` so 0 and 32 aren't strings in any way

Comment: Sorry to be so unapprehensive; but the API is so minimal. Maybe the log message is internationalized on the prefix length, and the route is indeed wrong, as 26, 0 and 8 are a bit strange. You could globally set the locale for testing: `Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);`.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is very late, but for documentation. This is a bug in Android itself. Google forgot in its own code a LOCALE.US so on the affected devices (iirc <=4.4?) you can only change the locale to a western locale that uses Western (what we western people call Arabic) numbers.